# Error:(1) String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'warp_content')

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="warp_content"
android:background="@drawable/background">
```

I don't know what's wrong,it seems that the data type is not proper? if I change the

```
android:layout_height="warp_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

It works. But I want to use warp_content,any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Change 
`android:layout_height="warp_content"`

to
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 1):

you should to use `wrap_content` not `warp_content` !

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```